# Proof of $\mathsf{SU}(3)/T^2$ is not a symmetric space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

1. How to see that $\mathsf{SU}(3)/T^2$ is **not** a symmetric space? This is not obvious to me.
2. How to see that it admits a metric of positive curvature? The only clue that I know is the submersion $\mathsf{SU}(3)\to \mathsf{SU}(3)/T^2$ if I am not mistaken. Then O'Neill's formula guarantees its curvature is positive?

No matter which definition of symmetric spaces is assumed. e.g.  $\nabla R=0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. There are (at least) two interpretations of this.  First, you could be asking why $SU(3)/T^2$ does not admit any Riemannian metric which makes it a symmetric space.  Second, you could be asking whether the canonical metric on $SU(3)$ descends to a symmetric metric on $SU(3)/T^2$.

I'll answer the first version since it has the second as a special case.

First note that $SU(3)/T^2$ is simply connected.  Simply connected symmetric spaces are completely classified by Cartan.  The short version is that each is isometric to a product of so-called irreducible pieces and all the possible pieces have been classified up to isometry.  The pieces come in two varieties:  they are either isometric to a compact simple simply connected Lie group $G$ with bi-invariant metric, or given as a quotient $G/H$ where $G$ is simple and simply connected, and $H$ is the identity component fixed point set of non-trivial involution $\sigma:G\rightarrow G$.  From the table under "classification" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space), note that for every $G/H$, $H$ has an at most one-dimensional circle factor.  In particular, $G/H$ has second Betti number at most $1$.  Since $SU(3)/T^2$ has second Betti number $=2$ (from the long exact sequence in homotopy groups together with the Hurewicz thoerem), $SU(3)/T^2$ cannot appear on either of these two lists.

So now it's just a matter of showing the $SU(3)/T^2$ is not diffeomorphic to a product of things as in the previous paragraph.  To that end, note that $SU(3)/T^2$ is a simply connected $6$-manifold with second Betti number $2$ with Euler characteristic $6$.  Thus, it cannot be any irreducible piece, so it must be a product.  But, if $SU(3)/T^2$ were diffeomorphic to a product, it would have to be homeomorphic to $S^2\times \mathbb{C}P^2$ by Freedman's classification of simply connected $4$-manifolds.  However, $\pi_4(S^2)\neq 0$, while $\pi_4(SU(3)/T^2) = 0$.  The latter calculation follows since $\pi_4(SU(3))  = 0$, which follows from Bott Periodicity.

2. This is tricky because a bi-invariant metric on $SU(3)$ does *not* descend to a positively curved metric on $SU(3)/T^2$.  Rather, one have to pick a particular left invariant metric which is still $T^2$-invariant on the right.  (In fact, it's $U(2)$ invariant on the right.)

The technique here is called a "Cheeger deformation".  Namely, you consider a subgroup of $K$ in $G$ and look at product metrics on $G\times K$.  There is a natural isometric $K$ action on $G\times K$ given by $k\ast(g,k') = (gk^{-1}, kk')$, and it's not too hard to see that $(G\times K)/K$ is diffeomorphic to $G$.  Since the $K$ action is isometric, this induces a new metric on $G$ which turns out to be left $G$-invariant and right $K$-invariant.  Since it's a submersion metric, O'Neill's formulas imply that the new metric on $G$ is non-negatively curved, but it actually has fewer zero-curvature planes than a bi-invariant metric on $G$, at least if $K$ is non-abelian.

This is the metric you use.  When you try to this on $U(2)\subseteq SU(3)$, what ends up happening is that for orthonormal $X,Y\in T_e G$, the sectional curvature of of the plane spanned by $X$ and $Y$ is non-negative, and is $0$ iff both $[X,Y]=0$ and $[X_\mathfrak{k},Y_{\mathfrak{k}}] = 0$.

For $SU(3)/T^2$ one shows that if there orthornomal $X,Y\in T_{eT^2} SU(3)/T^2$ spanning a zero-curvature plane, then their horizontal lifts to $T_e G$ satisfy the previous two equations.   Of course "horizontal" adds another equation, and one can then show the *three* equations are incompatible.  (I guess it's really *six* equations since three more are hiding in "orthonormal".)

Comment: OMG, I thought the argument would be very simple!!

Comment: Jason, this question is same as yours: $SU(3)/T^2$ is not _diffeomorphic_ to any symmetric spaces.

Comment: Well, especially for question 1, there may be a significantly easier approach.  For example, I believe you can use the cohomology ring of $SU(3)/T^2$ to show it's not a product.

Comment: Or you could find an invariant differential form that is not closed. That's my favorite trick, but I haven't tried to see how the Lie algebra of $T^2$ sits as a summand.

Comment: @Ted: That would, indeed, be a lot easier. The Lie algebra of $T^2$ sits in the obvious way. Namely, identifying $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ with the $3\times 3$ skew-Hermitian matrices, $\mathfrak{t}^2$ is precisely the subspace of diagonal matrices.  I'm too tired right now to find an invariant non-closed form, but I'd guess it's not too hard.

Comment: @Jason: If $\omega_{ij}$ are the Maurer-Cartan forms of $SU(3)$, I nominate $\phi = \omega_{12}\wedge\bar\omega_{12} + \omega_{13}\wedge\bar\omega_{13}$.

Comment: @Ted:  Now that I think about it, would your approach rule out $SU(3)/T^2$ from being a symmetric space?  It would show that $G$ can't induce a symmetric space structure on $SU(3)/T^2$, but there could be a transitive action by some other group which does.  In fact, something like this happens when considering $SU(3)/SU(2)$ instead.  There is no involution of $SU(3)$ which only fixes $SU(2)$.  But, of course, $SU(3)/SU(2)\cong S^5 \cong SO(6)/SO(5)$ is a symmetric space.

Comment: @Ted: (Continued)   Also, I admittedly haven't yet tried the computation you suggested, but does the notation $\omega_{12}$ indicate the form which returns the $12$-component of a vector left translated to the identity $I\in SU(3)$?  I have actually never worked with the Maurer-Cartan form, so this seems like a good way to get my hands dirty.

Comment: Yes, you're right that I am working with an invariant metric on $SU(3)$. My standard example of this computation is a (non-Grassmannian) flag space. I gave a few examples in my thesis many moons (complex kinematic formulas).

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Is there a more familiar topological space s.t it is homeomorphic to $\mathsf{SU}(3)/T^2$? Or I should call it just $\mathsf{SU}(3)/T^2$ itself? (I meant e.g. $SU(3)/SU(2)$ is $S^5$).

Comment: @C.F.G.:  It's a fiber bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with fiber $S^2$, but it's not the trivial bundle.  That's the best description I know in terms of familiar spaces.